# Scaling a TCP/IP based system and ensuring high availability

Tags: scalability, distributed, high-availability, tcp

I have a TCP/IP based component which is communicating with a c++ based system. In fact it is reading raw bytes from that system and then marshaling those raw bytes in objects and storing it in the DB. This multi-threaded tcp/ip based component is in java and could be deployed on a dual core or quad core processor (not sure if its important for my question but nevertheless a detail I am giving). Now I have a few questions:

1. How can I scale this tcp/ip based component. This component is deployed on a server and is listening to a port. In future if there's more data that is envisaged at this point that comes from the C++ system we should be able to scale this java component.
2. What about security. One thing which I can probably do is employ this communication on secure sockets or probably get encrypted data (any particular encryption that I could use here??). Any other way to take care of security?
3. There is also a requirement of high availability to be satisfied. How do I handle that? How could I possible have redundancy here?

Yes, we are working on the system architecture of a product and therefore, I was wondering if some experienced architect or designer could help me.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I scale this tcp/ip based component. This component is deployed on a server and is listening to a port. In future if there's more data that is envisaged at this point that comes from the C++ system we should be able to scale this java component.

You normally use a network load-balancer to scale these kind of services across multiple servers.  That load-balancer can distribute load using a variety of algorithms, such as:

- CPU load (usually measured with snmp)
- Client ip address (if you need persistence when mapping clients to your services)
- Number of active sockets
- etc

Look at [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) for a popular open-source load-balancer.  [F5](http://www.f5.com/) has the most popular commercial load-balancer solution.

> What about security. One thing which I can probably do is employ this communication on secure sockets or probably get encrypted data (any particular encryption that I could use here??). Any other way to take care of security?

- As mentioned, SSL is an option, but understand that is a big performance hit on your services if you encrypt on the same hardware that is performing your customer services.  One option along these lines is using a commercial load-balancer that implements SSL in hardware; that load-balancer would then forward unencrypted sockets to your TCP services farm.
- Under some circumstances you can use [IPSec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) network-level encryption; often, this is another network hardware solution. Typically your clients will download an IPSec application that resides on their PC... then they make a connection into your IPSec server, which encrypts between their client and your IPSec termination point
- [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) Tunneling with port-forwarding (low-tech solution)
- [tcpcrypt](http://tcpcrypt.org/) looks interesting as a future technology, but I'm not sure how mature it is right now.

> There is also a requirement of high availability to be satisfied. How do I handle that? How could I possible have redundancy here?

A lot depends on what you mean by high availability, and what kind of recovery timing you need.  At a high level, you have a few options:

- DNS-based HA works if you don't need client to socket mapping persistence; if you use DNS, you need to be willing to accept typical DNS A-record timeouts (usually people don't go lower than ~5 minutes / 300 seconds).  This also assumes you find a way to synchronize your databases across multiple sites.
- Load-balancer solutions.  Same issue with synchronizing back-end databases

To do any kind of HA, you probably want to hire a consultant that has a proven track record of implementing these services (if you don't have this kind of resource in-house).

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate answer mike, its really helpful.  so would a load balancer would also do failover? I mean for HA i believe load balancing + failover is the key right? Also, one thing i forgot to add was that we also have a scalability and HA requirement for our DB? What approach should we take? Would scaling horizontally make sense for DBs? Also, an important doubt .... am i correctly understanding that HA is more of configuration and there;s nothing i need to care about during design or coding?

Comment: @aryann, a load-balancer can support HA configurations, but again **a lot depends on what you mean by high availability**.  Two people can require HA for a service and it can mean vastly different things to both of them.  As for DB HA, talk to your DB vendor; most of them support some kind of multi-site replication.  Finally, HA involves design, configuration, and possibly software requirements.  I have seen many bad HA designs in my 15 years of networking... that is why I say: **Get an HA consultant, don't depend on free advice from people who don't know your environment & requirements**